# Default location of express generator title object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, express-generator

I'm using the express generator to create the framework for a site, which by default includes this line in the **layout.jade** file:

```
h1= title
```

Which calls in the title 'Express' from a local variable (**index.jade** extends the **layout.jade** file). However, I can't for the life of me find out where it's getting the variable from.

Can anyone tell me where the express generator creates the file that creates this variable, given I have used the default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the routes directory inside the index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' }); // <= HERE in the res.render method
});

module.exports = router;
```

You will find the object, passed as the second argument to the render method, that includes the key value pair `{title: 'Express'}`

Comment: How strange. I wouldn't have expected the title to have been created in the routes section! Learn something new every day.